# Inserting attribute to a join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I want to insert a value into a join table attribute whenever I do an insert through my AR models. I'm using an HMT association with all the affected models.

It's arranged as follows... I have an accounts table model:

```
class TabAccount < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tab_client_project_accounts
  has_many :tab_projects, through: :tab_client_project_accounts
end
```

That uses a join table model:

```
class TabClientProjectAccount < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :tab_account
  belongs_to :tab_project
end
```

To join to a project table model:

```
class TabProject < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tab_client_project_accounts
  has_many :tab_accounts, through: :tab_client_project_accounts
end
```

In my controller I use the shovel operator to add accounts to projects:

```
@this_project.tab_accounts << _new_account unless @this_project.tab_accounts.include?(_new_account)
```

And it works as designed. But I also want to insert a value into my `tab_client_project_accounts` join table as part of that shovel operator. Is that possible? What's the normal best practice for doing this?

Answer (score 2):

If you need more columns in the join table the `<<` approach (without explicitly using the join table) will not work as it does not set any additional attribute. You can use the join model instead:

Your version (without the join table):

```
@this_project.tab_accounts << _new_account unless @this_project.tab_accounts.include?(_new_account)
```

Using the join table:

```
@this_project.tab_client_project_accounts.build(
  tab_account: _new_account, 
  additional_data: 'anything_you_need'
) unless @this_project.tab_accounts.include?(_new_account)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response; it helped me to get to my final working solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do

```
tp = TabProject.find 1

tp.tab_client_project_accounts.build tab_account: TabAccount.find 1
```

or

```
tp.tab_client_project_accounts.build tab_account: TabAccount.create(name: 'Some Account Name')

tp.save!
```

This will ensure record in all the tables

Answer (score 0):

I just got it working as intended; this is what I have:

```
_account_type_list_member_id = RefAccountType.find_by_typename('List Member').id

@this_project.tab_client_project_accounts.build(
  :tab_account => _new_account,
  :ref_account_type_id => _account_type_list_member_id
).save unless @this_project.tab_accounts.include?(_new_account)
```